# JavaScript split() using a common character then join() using different characters

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

Assuming I have a string: **`/someFolder/anotherFolder/fileName`** and I want to replace all the forward slashes with a `"+"` then this would work:

```
var someString = '/someFolder/anotherFolder/fileName'
someString.split('/').join('+');
```

Or using regex, this would work:

```
var someString = '/someFolder/anotherFolder/fileName'
someString.replace(/\//g, "+");
```

---

But what would be the best approach if I want to replace the first occurence with a '+' then the second occurence with another character like say, the '-', the third with '*' and so on so that the string `someString` above returns:

```
+someFolder-anotherFolder*fileName
```

Comment: It is not quite clear what you mean, but looks like `someString.replace('/', '+').replace('/', '-').replace('/', '*');` should suffice.

Comment: `.replace()` method can receive a callback function as second argument. That has an `offset` parameter.

Comment: ...the point being that a REGEX pattern without the `g` flag will only ever replace the next found match.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Wouldn't the first replace method convert the forward slash already thus making the second replace method not find any forward slash anymore?

Comment: @AndrewL `.replace` with a string as the first argument  only replaces the first occurrence.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Can you please post it as a solution so I can vote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may chain several [`String#replace()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) calls with a literal string as the search argument to achieve what you need:

```js
var someString = '/someFolder/anotherFolder/fileName';
console.log(someString.replace('/', '+').replace('/', '-').replace('/', '*'));
```

The point here is that non-regex search argument makes it find the *first* occurrence only, and since you have three different replacement strings (`+`, `-` and `*`) it is not quite convenient/straight forward to use a regex.

Answer (score 6):

You can pass a function to `replace()`:

```js
let someString = "/someFolder/anotherFolder/file";
const repl = [ '+', '-', '*' ];
let i = 0;
console.log(someString.replace(/\//g, (match) => repl[(i++) % repl.length]));
```

Comment: Didn't thought of using a a function to do this. Nice one man. +1

Answer (score 4):

You could use an index and a string for getting the wanted character as a closure or take an array if you have more than one character.

```js
var someString = '/someFolder/anotherFolder/fileName'

console.log(someString.replace(/\//g, (i => _ => "+-*"[i++])(0)));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `reduce` method by passing an **arrow** function as `argument`.

```js
var someString = '/someFolder/anotherFolder/fileName'
someString = someString.split('/').slice(1).reduce((str, item, index) => str + "+-*"[index] + item, "");
console.log(someString);
```

Comment: Thank you Mihai. This es6 approach works beautifully. +1